# Angular : get/access selected item from <select>?

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to find a way to access the selected-item in select-box from javascript. Have been looking for a day !
All that I'm getting back is how to set the selected OR react via ng-change.

I was thinking of storing the item when the selection changes but this seems ridiculous to me , there have to be a better way !

do you know a way ?

---

I got it thanks..

I just have to directly access the ng-model var ...f.e. ctrl.form.field_name and I'm getting back the value/id.

Is there a way to grab the option label ?

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully address your additional request.  Let me know if that solves your issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the selected item from the ng-model value.  Something like this should do it:

```
<select ng-model="thing"
ng-options="thing.id as thing.name for thing in things track by thing.name">
```

This will give you the `thing` object as the ng-model value.

Comment: @user1019129 I know you said the above worked for you, did the update help as well?   If so please marked as correct to better document an answer to your problem.  Thanks!